# webdav access a textfile line by line

Tags: webdav

I have looked all over (spent about 7 hours).  I have found numerous articles on how to map a drive (google drive, onedrive etc).  What I cannot seem to find an answer to is this:  Once I have mapped the drive can I use the files on that drive just like I use files on a server.  Open the file, read a record, write a record.  I have created a file, mapped a network drive, wrote records to the file and retrieved records from the file.  I have a home grown database that is implemented with a large binary (as opposed to text) file.  I have to go to a byte position and read a fixed number of bytes.  If WebDAV is copying the file to my computer and then writing it back this would make my file access way to slow and I cannot seem to find an answer.  Some programmers I have talked to say I cannot even do that, yet I can.  Any direction would be very much appreciated.

Charlie

Answer (score 0):

That's likely because standard WebDAV doesn't allow updating ranges of resources only, so the whole thing needs to be written back.

Comment: Thanx,  what I can't figure out is who (what?) is sending and receiving records?  myProgram sends 1 line of text to --> Windows OS who sends the line to --> WebDAV server who updates the line  (Does the server send the whole file to Windows and Windows updates the file?)  Why can't I find a definitive answer to this?